# Trying to Create a script that will get my filtered list of Get-Adcomputer then run a command on each

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

Firstly, 
 I am very new to powershell. Everytime I think i get the logic i go WTF.. If this was bash it would be so easy etc..

what am I trying to do exactly ...

Get all computers from AD that Meet the `Xiopwb*` criteria. Once i have the list I need to change the permissions on the `\\Xiopwb20\Nsiwebroot` Directory to ONLY INCLUDE Domain Administrators and A Security group "webadmins"

My Logic:

Get all computers from AD that meet `Xio*PWB*`
Take just the NAME of objects in that list 
for ever "name" in that list do `Get-ACL \\Name from list\Nsiwebroot`
remove *
add user / group.

What I have:

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ADComputer -filter * | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "xiopwb*"} | Select Name |  ForEach-Object { Get-Acl \\$_.Name\nsiwebroot}
```

all up to the "ForEach" works...  I get just the names of the PC's that I need etc..

Simple as possible I don't need a 100 line script.

Thanks

** update **

it is double \ its just not showing it... no idea why

Looks like it is doing what I want to a degree. However its spitting out the format funky. `@{Name=XIOPWB09}`

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Get-ADComputer -filter * | Where-Object {$_.Name -like "xiopwb*"} | Select Name | ForEach-Object {get-acl "\\$_\D$\nsiwebroot"}
```

> get-acl : Cannot find path '\@{Name=XIOPWB09}\D$\nsiwebroot' because it does not exist.
>   At line:1 char:99
>   + ... opwb*"} | Select Name | ForEach-Object {get-acl "\$_\D$\nsiwebroot"}
>   +                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-Acl], ItemNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetAcl_PathNotFound_Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand
>
> get-acl : Cannot find path '\@{Name=XIOPWB06}\D$\nsiwebroot' because it does not exist.
>   At line:1 char:99
>   + ... opwb*"} | Select Name | ForEach-Object {get-acl "\$_\D$\nsiwebroot"}
>   +                                             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (:) [Get-Acl], ItemNotFoundException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetAcl_PathNotFound_Exception,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetAclCommand

Comment: What is `\Xiopwb20\Nsiwebroot` ? That's not a valid path. Is it supposed to be `\\Xiopwb20\Nsiwebroot` and you want to change the *share* permissions? Or is it supposed to be `\\Xiopwb20\c$\Nsiwebroot\ ` to get something on the remote disk through the admin share? Or is it something like `c:\xiopwb20\nsiwebroot` a path on the local disk named after the computer?

Comment: 1) It wouldn't be at all easy to get AD computers and change Windows ACLs in bash. 2) Your `where-object` is broken because `$.Name` is not a thing, it needs to be `$_.Name`. And you could do that filtering in `Get-ADComputer -filter "Name -like 'xiopwb*'"` part. 3) Your `| select Name |` is doing effectively nothing at all. 4) Your `get-acl \$.Name` is broken for the same reason you need `$_.Name` and you possibly need double quotes around the path.

Comment: you would need double quotes around the path, and then need to change $_.Name to $($_.Name) so that it will process correctly.  That also only gets you to the point of having the ACL object, which you then need to manipulate and apply with Set-ACL, which is not exactly easy to do within a single pipeline.

Comment: @MikeGaruccio that worked! $($_.Name) .. could you maybe explain why that works just $_.Name does not?

Comment: It's because you are trying to use the variable within a string, `"$_.Name"` gets interpreted as you wanting a string that begins with whatever is contained in the variable `$_` followed by the string `".Name"`.  so for example if the object you piped in was just a string `"foo"` `"$_.Name"` would yield the string `'foo.Name'` placing your variable call inside of $() tells powershell to first evaluate what the variable contained within the parentheses is, then place it in the larger string.

Answer (score 1):

"`Select Name`" returns an Object with Table Header Name. "`Select -ExpandProperty Name`" is What needed here, which will convert it o String.

Regards,

kvprasoon